# Adding time slots through trigger SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008, trigger

I am quite new to SQL. I am now working on something to schedule appointments.
I found an existing answer about time slots, but did not quite understand.

I need to automatically add time slots to the timeslots table according to the availability table. if availability from start at 10:00 and end at 16:00, and duration is 60 minutes, I need to insert 6 time slot rows.

Would you please be kind enough to let me know what I should do?
Do I need to do it through a trigger? Or do I need to redesign my schema?

My trigger is like this, apparently not really working:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_addSlots ON availability
    FOR INSERT AS
    BEGIN
        declare @AvailabilityId int
        declare @SlotStart DateTime
        declare @SlotEnd DateTime
        declare @NumberOfSlots int
        declare @Duration int
        declare @SlotDoctorId int
        declare @i int

        Select @AvailabilityId = Id from inserted
        Select @SlotDoctorId =DoctorId from inserted
        Select @SlotStart =AvailableFrom from inserted
        Select @SlotEnd = AvailableTo from inserted 
        Select @Duration = AppointmentDuration from inserted

        set @NumberOfSlots = convert (int, (@SlotEnd - @SlotStart))/@Duration

        set @i = 0;
        While @i<@NumberOfSlots
          Begin

            insert into timeslots(AvailabilityId, SlotStart, SlotEnd, 
            SlotDoctorId,IsAvailable) values (@AvailabilityId, @SlotStart, 
            @SlotStart+@Duration,
            @SlotDoctorId,1)
            Set @SlotStart = @SlotEnd
            Set @SlotEnd = @SlotEnd + @Duration
            set @i=@i+1
          End

    END
```

#### schema

[image]

Comment: What happens if someone updates?

Answer (score 2):

Your `schema` looks fine but you need to calculate the dates in a different way, 
In `T-SQL` you can't just add and subtract.

`@NumberOfSlots` calculation should be like this:

```
    set @NumberOfSlots = convert (int, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @SlotStart, @SlotEnd)))/@Duration
```

adding to a `datetime` is done like this:

```
    DATEADD(MINUTE, @Duration, @SlotStart)
```

The order in the loop needs to be changed too:

```
    set @i = 0;
    While @i<@NumberOfSlots
        Begin
           Set @SlotEnd = DATEADD(MINUTE, @Duration, @SlotStart)
           insert into timeslots
           (AvailabilityId, SlotStart, SlotEnd, SlotDoctorId,IsAvailable) 
           values 
           (@AvailabilityId, @SlotStart, @SlotEnd, @SlotDoctorId,1)
           Set @SlotStart = @SlotEnd

           set @i=@i+1
        End
```

With these changes, I think the trigger will work and give correct values, but
that is a lot of work in a trigger.

I think you should consider solving this by building stored procedures doing the same, leaving the tables with data and no logic.

One stored procedure per table, that inserts a row to that table.

For 'Availability' the stored procedure could be `createAvailability` and the code would be very similar to what you have in the trigger, but in the loop it calls the stored procedure to create a row in Timeslots:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE createAvailability 
    (
        @AvailabilityId INT, 
        @SlotStart DATETIME, 
        @SlotEnd DATETIME, 
        @SlotDoctorId INT
    ) AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @i INT
        DECLARE @NumberOfSlots INT 
        DECLARE @Duration INT 

        SET @NumberOfSlots = convert(INT, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @SlotStart,@SlotEnd))) / @Duration
        SET @i = 0;
        WHILE @i < @NumberOfSlots
        BEGIN
            SET @SlotEnd = DATEADD(MINUTE, @Duration, @SlotStart)
            EXEC createTimeslots(@AvailabilityId, @SlotStart, @SlotEnd, @SlotDoctorId, 1)
            SET @SlotStart = @SlotEnd
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
    END
```

Comment: your help is so valuable, many thanks.
trigger is working after I made changes as per your instructions.
Now I am trying to figure out the stored procedure way to do the same thing.
really appreciated your enormous help, cheers.
Zoe